# AWS User data windows standard AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to use codedeploy with autoscaling in order to automate the deployment of my application.

I have everything ready. When developing all the parts (hooks' scripts, roles etc) I installed the codedeploy agent manually. Now I want to make it production ready, which means that the codedeploy agent will be installed at sysprep (by providing the powershell commands via user data in launch configuration).

The problem is that it's not working. The script either runs and fails for some reason (are there any logs to confirm?) or it doesn't run at all. My AMI is based on a aws standard windows AMI. The EC2ConfigService is present.

Do you have any idea of what could be the problem or if I have some way to find what's the problem (logs)?

Comment: did you solve this?  what was the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at  C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Logs\Ec2ConfigLog.txt

On Linux AMIs you can also find the user data script execution logs in the ec2 console when you right click your instance -> Instance Settings -> Get System Log.